# When to use Application_Start vs Init in Global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I am wondering under what circumstances I should be putting application initialisation code in `Application_Start()` vs `Init()` in my `Global.asax` file?

The distinction between the two doesn't seem very obvious to me, other than `Application_start` gets called first, then `Init()`.

- Why would I use one over the other?
- Does it really make a difference?
- What changes in the application state
  between the two events?

So far the only real pointer I can find is that `IHttpModule` only has an `Init()` method, so if what I'm doing may at some point be better suited to implement `IHttpModule` I should use the `Init()` method of `Global.asax`, if nothing else for consistency.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29):

> The Application_Start and Application_End methods are special methods that do not represent HttpApplication events. ASP.NET **calls them once for the lifetime of the application domain, not for each HttpApplication instance**.

Init:

> Called **once for every instance of the
>   HttpApplication** class after all
>   modules have been created.

UPDATE: if you need to make sure a certain code is called only once in the app. lifecycle, Application_Start is a better solution. Examples: configuring log4net?

Comment: Bit of a follow-up question: when is an instance of HttpApplication created? I'm assuming each time the worker-process is restarted and it will contain one instance for each worker-thread?

Comment: @roryf - asp.net maintains a pool of application instances that can be resused. Under the covers, requests are serviced using the CLR threadpool and incoming requests will be queued beyond a certain threshold. I doubt they initialize the application instance pool to that threshold level since most sites won't see that kind of traffic. I suspect they create the pool with a small number of instances and then increase the size of the pool as demand ramps up.

Answer (score 13):

Yes

There are differences between them. Application_Start() event is called just one time while Init() method is called on each time when instance of the application is created.