# When are the Init methods of HttpModule called?

Tags: asp.net, .net, httpmodule

I known each HttpApplication owns an HttpModule. And there are many HttpApplications created by an ASP.NET web app. So each HttpApplication init method would be called. When did HttpModule.Init happen? In another words, what object are in charge of the initialization of HttpModule?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140915/httpmodule-init-method-is-called-several-times-why or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370839/advanced-how-many-times-does-httpmodule-init-method-get-called-during-applica