# Ninject Creating an Extra Instance when using NinjectHttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

For some reason Ninject is creating an additional instance of my object when I use `NinjectHttpModule` in my MVC 4 app.

If I use `NinjectHttpModule` (the Ninject.MVC3 default) but do not actually have any `IHttpModule` classes that require constructor injection, it works fine.  But as soon as I create a class that implements `IHttpModule` and that requires constructor injection, Ninject for some reason creates two instances of my object.

I added some tracking code to the class that is being duplicated to verify that it was being duplicated.  Every time an instance is created, the static count variable is incremented:

```
namespace Trigger.Events
{
    public class TriggerEventRegistry : ITriggerRegistry
    {
        private static int count;

        public TriggerEventRegistry()
        {
            TriggerEventRegistry.count++;
        }
    }
 }
```

Here is my `IHttpModule`:

```
namespace TriggerDevelopment.ApplicationTriggers
{
    public class RegisterTriggerComponentsHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
        ITriggerEventRegistry eventRegistry;

        public RegisterTriggerComponentsHttpModule(ITriggerEventRegistry eventRegistry)
        {
            this.eventRegistry = eventRegistry;
        }
     }
     ....
}
```

By the time a `TriggerEventRegistry` is injected into my controller (on the same request), the `TriggerEventRegistry.count` equals `2`.  If I comment out the constructor on `RegisterTriggerComponentsHttpModule`, then the value of `TriggerEventRegistry.count` equals `1` (which is should since there should only be one instance/request).

Here is the binding code:

```
Bind<ITriggerEventRegistry>().To<TriggerEventRegistry>().InRequestScope();
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

**Note**

I even made a request to my app using curl to avoid multiple HTTP requests being made by the browser looking for assets, a favicon or something like that. Still no joy.

**Update**

Upon further investigation, I'm also seeing that the ctor and the `Init` method of `RegisterTriggerComponentsHttpModule` is being called twice.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line: `TriggerEventRegistry.count++;` and confirm what the callstack looks like and that it's Ninject that is responsible for both instantiations.

Comment: Both times the instance is created by Ninject...StandardProvider.Create

Comment: possible duplicate of [HttpModule Init method is called several times - why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140915/httpmodule-init-method-is-called-several-times-why)

Comment: What about creating an object id for ``System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request`` to ensure it's really one request and not two. Do you use the ``OnePerRequestModule`` like it is described in the Ninject documentation. We had a similar issue where ``.InRequestScope`` behaved like transient scope without the use of this module.

Comment: What happens if you add `[Inject]` to the constructor of your `IHttpModule`?

Comment: is it possible that the app is actually being hit twice? a common case is when trying the app in a browser, it would also send a request for the favicon. Try to look at IIS logs, or hook a proxy (fiddler) to see if this is the case

Answer (score 0):

It's going to call your HttpModule as many times as there are requests.  For instance, most web browsers submit at least two requests, the page request and a favicon request.  Try adding something like an image to the page, and see if you get three requests...