# 404 Errors for WebAPI - Registering routes in HttpModule not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, .net-4.5

I am trying to add WebAPI endpoints to an existing forms application but I am getting 404 errors.

I cannot use the Global.asax `Application_Start()` to register the api routes as suggested by [Microsoft here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms) because the current application already has a compiled customization of the Global class which inherits from `HttpApplication` and they did not mark any of the methods as `virtual`. doh!

I am trying to load the routes using an HttpModule. I am getting 404 errors for the following URL:
`https://example.com/webapplication/myapi/Authorize/User`

Module code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

public class MyHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    private static bool HasAppStarted = false;
    private readonly static object _syncObject = new object();

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        //https://stackoverflow.com/a/2416546/579148
        if (!HasAppStarted)
        {
            lock (_syncObject)
            {
                if (!HasAppStarted)
                {
                    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config => RegisterRoutes.Load(config));
                    HasAppStarted = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable Implementation
    #endregion
}
```

My registration class is in a standalone library:

```
using System.Web.Http;

public static class RegisterRoutes
{
    public static void Load(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "myapi/{controller}");
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;
using MyLibrary.Models;

[Route("myapi/[controller]/[action]")]
public class AuthorizeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, ActionName("User")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public WebUser GetUser()
    {
        WebUser user = new WebUser();
        user.Key = Guid.Empty.ToString();
        return user;
    }
}
```

And finally the web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <!--...-->
  <system.webServer>
    <!--...-->
    <modules>
      <add name="MyModule" type="MyLibrary.MyHttpModule" />
    </modules>
    <!--...-->
  </system.webServer>
  <!--...-->
<configuration>
```

The `webapplication` is its own IIS application (its own Global.asax and web.config). I am on Windows 10, CLR version v4.0, and Managed Pipeline is Integrated.

I've tried several other options described [here](https://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/), [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2070064.aspx?Web%20API%202%20URL%20routing%20404%20error%20on%20IIS%207%205%20IIS%20Express%20works%20fine), and [here](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html) but have not had anything but 404s.

TIA!

Comment: You are mixing up frameworks. `[Route("myapi/[controller]/[action]")]` is for [tag:asp.net-core] while your code appears to be for [tag:asp.net-web-api]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the `MapHttpRoute()` method call. It seems that the routing does not like *not* having a value for the `defaults` and `constraints` parameters. I updated the map call to this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi", 
    routeTemplate: Constants.ApiBaseRoute + "/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new {  }, 
    constraints: new {  }
);
```

I also had to add the `action` template parameter. And I removed the route attributes on the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up frameworks. `[Route("myapi/[controller]/[action]")]` is for [asp.net-core](/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) while your code appears to be for [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api)

A few suggested changes.

Module code can be simplified

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(RegisterRoutes.Load);
```

Since attribute routing is configured

```
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Use the correct attributes on the `APIController` and action

```
[RoutePrefix("myapi/Authorize")]
public class AuthorizeController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet, ActionName("User")]
    [Route("user")] //GET myapi/authorize/user
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUser() {
        WebUser user = new WebUser();
        user.Key = Guid.Empty.ToString();
        return Ok(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Nkosi. I forgot to mention in my answer that I removed the attribute routes that I included in my question. I used the configure lambda because I will end up piping that `config` var into a couple of other calls. Also, I see that you are returning an action result type. What the pro/con on just returning the type directly? I have updated the serializers so that I the framework converts the types to JSON. I am currently getting a JSON response back from my API calls without using Action Result.

Comment: @jwatts1980 using the action result allows more flexibility for returning different http responses. using the plain object will always return HTTP 200 OK unless an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was very helpful. I have updated to  However, adding the `new { }` declaration to the `defaults` and `constraints` parameters as indicated by my answer was what finally made it start working.