# Add Application Start event handler manually in constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

In `Global`, as an alternative to the application `AutoEventWireups`, it seems that events are exposed for most of the underlying Application events (`BeginRequest, AuthorizeRequest, Error`, etc), as well as a set of asynch methods like `AddOnBeginRequestAsync` etc. However, I cannot find an equivalent event for `ApplicationStart`!

So my question is, is there anyway to subscribe to the 'same' event that the `AutoEventWireup` method `Application_(On)Start` is hooked into?

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    public Global()
    {
        // I can do this ...
        base.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(Global_BeginRequest);
        // Or even AddOnBeginRequestAsync();

        // But how can I do this?
        base.ApplicationStart += new EventHandler(GlobalApplication_Start);
    }

    protected void Global_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // ...
    }

    protected void Global_ApplicationStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // ...
    }
}
```

(Out of interest ... is there a way to switch off the `AutoEventWireups` in Global.asax?. Using the AutoEventWireup = "false" attribute only seems to work on aspx pages)

**Edit** - it seems that ApplicationStart and ApplicationEnd "are special methods that do not represent [HttpApplication events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720969/when-to-use-application-start-vs-init-in-global-asax?rq=1)". So I might be barking up the wrong tree entirely.

**Edit**
Re : Why would I need this? Unfortunately, a corporate customer has a framework in place whereby new apps need to inherit their custom `HttpApplication` class, and FWR, their `HttpApplication` had already implemented the autowireup `Application_(On)Start`, meaning that I needed to find another way to override the Framework wireup, so that I can Bootstrap my IoC container and Automapper maps. As per Lloyd's answer, I could also bootstrap in the ctor or `Init()` as well, although this isn't [quite the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720969/when-to-use-application-start-vs-init-in-global-asax?rq=1). Ultimately I was able to change the corporate framework to allow multiple subscriptions.

Comment: What is the end goal of this, there may be a better way to do what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could override Init:

```
public class MyApplication : HttpApplication
{

    public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();
    }

}
```

However your constructor could also work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Be really careful with the Init method.

Using Init method for code that you want to be executed once in the Application lifecycle is a bad option as the Init method is called once for every instance of the HttpApplication...

As you said ApplicationStart and ApplicationEnd are special methods that do not represent HttpApplication events but they work in a similar fashion to the Page events when the AutoEventWireups is set to true..

After jumping to the .NET source code i found that the HttpApplicationFactory class looks for a method named "Application_OnStart" or "Application_Start" in the Global.asax file and then invokes it using reflection => ReflectOnMethodInfoIfItLooksLikeEventHandler().

Check out my question about a similar subject: [HttpApplication.Start event does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650631/httpapplication-start-event-does-not-exist)