# Applicatoin_Start, Init, and horizontal scaling in Azure

Tags: azure, appdomain, horizontal-scaling, httpapplication

The terminology is a little unclear around horizontal scaling in Azure.

When it creates multiple instances of an application, I understand that these run in separate VMs, so when such horizontal scaling happens, this should cause entirely new AppDomains with their own set of static variables to be created.

If that's the case, then is it true that Application_Start event would be called for each instance?

We have a "cache flush" feature that involves setting up a listener to subscribe to a "topic" in a message queue, so that it will flush a static cache when a message is received. We used to think we had to set up the listener in the HttpApplication.Init event, which would be called for each instance, but that no longer makes sense, after realizing that all HttpApplication instances within the AppDomain share the same set of static variables.

My new understanding is that multiple HttpApplication instances (and therefore multiple calls to HttpApplication.Init) will occur in a web app even without horizontal scaling. In other words, it's a normal feature of how an asp.net web app handles requests even in a single AppDomain.  Azure's horizontal scaling is completely different, and involves instantiating entirely separate AppDomains.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Related, but doesn't answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720969/when-to-use-application-start-vs-init-in-global-asax

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, first, we need to know below two points:

1. `Application_Start` will only be invoked after the first `HttpApplication` object is created and subsequent `HttpApplication` instances that are created do not trigger this event.
2. Each `HttpApplication` instance will create a new set of `HttpModule` and call the Init method after it is created.

We can check the original code to see how `HttpApplication` is created:

[image]

We can find above code at `System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance`

So in single AppDomain, if there are not enough instances of `HttpApplication` when concurrent access occurs, new `HttpApplication` instances will be created and `HttpApplication.Init` will be called after every instance created. But `Application_Start` only be called once after the first `HttpApplication` instance created.

According to the above description, i think you should set up the listener in the `Application_Start` event. When horizontal scale happens, `Application_Start` will be called every time after the new AppDomain is created.